# Why are there no "natural" occurrences of high or low r.e sets?

Tags: computability-theory

The notions of a low and high sets were introduced, I think by Soare, in the context of the dense structure of degrees of those sets which are neither r.e. neither recursive. My question is:

*Why are all examples of "natural" decision problems (the spectral gap problem for example) reducible to the halting language and none are low or high?*

Comment: Can you find a natural decision problem reducible to the halting language and neither Turing complete nor recursive?

Comment: @喻良 I don't think I could